# How to load Drools Workbench artifacts from workbench internal git repository?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, drools

I am trying to load the drools workbench artifacts from its internal repository but it's failing with the below error:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2/com.test/ImportProducts/ImportProducts_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**

I have done the following things:

Added below lines in the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>ImportProducts</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>guvnor-m2-repo</id>
        <name>Guvnor M2 Repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Added below lines in settings.xml file located at "/opt/jboss/.m2/repository" in docker container.

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>drools-maven</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Below is my Java code:

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    System.out.println("KieServices: "+ks.toString());
    KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
    System.out.println("KieRepository: "+kr.toString());
    UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources()
            .newUrlResource("http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2/com.test/ImportProducts/ImportProducts_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    urlResource.setUsername("admin");
    urlResource.setPassword("admin");
    urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
    System.out.println("UrlResource: "+urlResource.toString());
    InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
    System.out.println("InputStream: "+is.toString());
    KieModule kModule = kr.addKieModule(ks.getResources()
            .newInputStreamResource(is));
    //ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId("com.test", "ImportProducts", "LATEST");
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kModule.getReleaseId());
    kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();

    KieSession kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
    kieSession.insert(facts);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  drools-wb:
    container_name: drools-wb
    volumes:
      - ./maven:/opt/jboss/.m2/repository
    image: jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8001:8001
    network_mode: default

  kie-wb:
    container_name: kie-wb
    image: jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
      -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false 
      -Dorg.kie.server.id=kieserver 
      -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://kie-wb:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server 
      -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://kie-wb:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller"
    links:
      - drools-wb:kie-wb
    network_mode: default
```

Looking at the logs says that maven rest end point is:

kie-wb       | Using 'http://172.17.0.2:8080/business-central/maven2' for the kie-workbench Maven repository URL

But I get 404 when I hit http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2
or even http://localhost:8180/business-central/maven2

Here's the log:

```
drools-wb    | Running Drools Workbench on JBoss Wildfly...
drools-wb    | JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
drools-wb    | =========================================================================
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    |   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    |   JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    |   JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    |   JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    | =========================================================================
drools-wb    |
drools-wb    | 02:56:50,235 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final
kie-wb       | Using 'kie-server-a270b63b6b1a' as KIE server identifier
kie-wb       | Detected successful link for KIE Workbench container. Applying automatic configuration for the link...
kie-wb       | Using 'http://172.17.0.3:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server' as KIE server location
kie-wb       | Using 'http://172.17.0.2:8080/business-central/rest/controller' as KIE server controller
kie-wb       | Using 'http://172.17.0.2:8080/business-central/maven2' for the kie-workbench Maven repository URL
kie-wb       | Running KIE Execution Server on JBoss Wildfly...
drools-wb    | 02:56:50,820 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.3.Final
kie-wb       | JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -Dorg.kie.server.id=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://kie-wb:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://kie-wb:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller
drools-wb    | 02:56:50,838 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
```

Please help!

Comment: If you get a 404 when you hit those URLs, it sounds like you're not actually running anything that's serving at those locations. Are you running a Maven repository at that location? Check your webserver configuration.

Comment: The log says maven is pointing to localhost:8080/business-central/mave2. Added log in my post.

Comment: Right so you told it to look for a maven repo at that url, but are you actually _running_ one there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Below are the changes I made:

Added the following lines in standalone-full-drools.xml

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.guvnor.m2repo.dir" value="/opt/jboss/.m2/repository"/>
    <property name="org.appformer.m2repo.url" value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2"/>
    <property name="kie.maven.settings.custom" value="/opt/jboss/.m2/repository/settings.xml"/>
</system-properties>
```

Added these lines to the code:

```
    StatelessKieSession kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
    ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(prepareCommands(facts, CLASS_NAME));
```